# YII : How to redirect in afterAction under component controller class "CController"

Tags: redirect, yii

I need your help to resolve my issue. I'm stuck here from approx 3-4 hours.

I made custom roles and permissions to every user. I have executed the code under component controller class's function afterAction. But if user don't have the access of the clicked action then it should be redirect to error page. When i use redirect function it says `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`. I will be highly thankful if anyone can help me out. Here is my code

```
if (isset(yii::app()->user->id)) {
    $controller = yii::app()->controller->id;
    $action = yii::app()->controller->action->id;

    $noAuthControllerAction = array();
    $noAuthControllerAction[] = 'site/index';

    $controllerAction = $controller . '/' . $action;

    if (!in_array($controllerAction, $noAuthControllerAction)) {
        $isAllowed = $this->isAllowed($controller, $action);
        if (!$isAllowed) {
            $this->redirect(array('site/denied'));
        }
    }
}
parent::afterAction($action);
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use accessRules() in your controller for roles and permissions for more information see [Yii Documentation for authentication and authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

**In your controller**

A basic role-based access control looks like this :

```
        array('allow', // allow authenticated owner users to perform the following actions.
            'actions' => array('sales', 'export', 'invoice', 'payment'),
            'users' => array('@'),
            'roles' => array('owner'),
        ),
```

A custom expression role-based access control looks like this : **(This is what you need)**

```
        array('deny', // deny authenticated owner users to perform the following actions if store is not yet selected.
            'actions' => array('sales', 'export', 'invoice', 'payment'),
            'users' => array('@'),
            'roles' => array('owner'),
            'deniedCallback' => function() {
        Yii::app()->controller->redirect(array('/store/location'));
    },
            'expression' => '!Yii::app()->user->isStoreSelected()',
        ),
```

**'expression'** is your rule, and if rule is not met then **'deniedCallback'** will redirect you to desired 'controller/action' in this case '/store/location'.

Also don't use 
`$this->redirect(array('site/denied'))` for error handling, instead use

`throw new CHttpException(401,'Access denied.');`

This is the right way to handle errors in Yii. If you want to customize your error page please refer to [Error Handling](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error)

Answer (score 0):

afterAction runs after action is rendered. This is the cause of your error.
Use beforeAction event for that. Do you know RBAC? RBAC can help you.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control

You could use accessControl for limit action uses to roles.